# Registry key not showing up in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: registry

When registering a COM server, I write some registry keys to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. All keys created in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive this way should show up in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive, correct ?

On one system (Windows Server 2008 64 bit) I work with, this is not the case.

I have reproduced this to a very simple case : I start regedit and add a key 'testit' to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes. On most systems this automatically shows up in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. On the Windows Server 2008 64 bit system in question, it does not.

On the server in question, if I create a test-123 key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT manually, the key also shows up in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Classes. This is normal.

I also tried adding the key 'testit' to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes after starting regedit as administrator. This did not change the behaviour.

This behavious seems very odd to me. Anyone else ever seen this ? Could it be because of certain policies ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this at all? I'm facing a similar problem